# Cannot Update a Devise Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using rails 4, and I was having issues with the permitted parameters.  I got them working for create, but not update...

I have an interesting set-up with devise.  I have two different devise models, and one belongs to another via database association.

My problem is that when I go to update, it sends me back to the edit page, it says please review the problems below, and there is nothing highlighted as an error would indicate.

The server looks like this, but I don't see an error...

```
Started PUT "/clients" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-08 18:19:14 -0400
Processing by Client::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
Processing by Client::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jHJRAX3ML8AYEGbwCDYcsbuFbvPUk5RDQEK87LIQObA=", "client"=>{"first_name"=>"Kanye", "last_name"=>"West", "rate"=>"2000", "email"=>"patrick@shiftedrecording.com", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000106883658 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dp/9ll62dd16fn75857f5_8kf_m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140708-14658-3l4eyr>, @original_filename="kanye.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client[image]\"; filename=\"kanye.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "engineer_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jHJRAX3ML8AYEGbwCDYcsbuFbvPUk5RDQEK87LIQObA=", "client"=>{"first_name"=>"Kanye", "last_name"=>"West", "rate"=>"2000", "email"=>"patrick@shiftedrecording.com", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000106883658 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dp/9ll62dd16fn75857f5_8kf_m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140708-14658-3l4eyr>, @original_filename="kanye.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client[image]\"; filename=\"kanye.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "engineer_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
Client Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = 16  ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Client Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = 16  ORDER BY "clients"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Client Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
Client Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
Engineer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "engineers".* FROM "engineers"  WHERE "engineers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Engineer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "engineers".* FROM "engineers"  WHERE "engineers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Engineer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "engineers".* FROM "engineers"
Engineer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "engineers".* FROM "engineers"
Rendered clients/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (13.9ms)
Rendered clients/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (13.9ms)
Studio Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "studios".* FROM "studios"   ORDER BY "studios"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Studio Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "studios".* FROM "studios"   ORDER BY "studios"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 68.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

I don't even see a commit...I'm also not certain why there is so much duplication but that's not really my issue (unless it is)

First -> application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

and

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :rate, :engineer_id, :image) }
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :rate, :engineer_id, :image) }
end
```

This should apply to BOTH models, as it is in my application_controller...

Next, my overridden clients/registration_controller

```
class Client::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:new, :create]
 def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  resource_saved = resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource_saved
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      flash[:success] = "New Client Added"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    respond_with resource
  end
 end
 def update
  self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
  prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

  resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource_updated
    if is_flashing_format?
      flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
        :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
      set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
    end
    sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
    respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords resource
    respond_with resource
  end
 end
end
```

I'll post my routes for good measure

```
devise_for :clients, :controllers => {:registrations => "client/registrations"}
   resources :clients, :only => [:show, :new, :edit, :update]

devise_for :engineers, :controllers => {:registrations => "engineer/registrations"}
   resources :engineers, :only => [:show]

devise_scope :client do
  get "clients/:id", to: "clients#show" 
end
```

Why doesn't my resource update?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you need to pass a parameter called `current_password` in order to update a user via RegistrationsController.

Comment: Hmm, no sign of that from the server log but I'll give it a shot